# Is it possible to get previous entry in @HandleAfterSave event with Spring Data REST?

Tags: spring-data-rest

I have next event handler:

```
@Component
@RepositoryEventHandler
public class EntityEventHandler {

    private final EntityService entityService;

    @HandleAfterSave
    public void handleAfterSave(final Entity entity) {
        // need old entity here to validate if specific field has changed
    }
}
```

Is there any way to get old entity in `handleAfterSave` ?

Comment: I normally simply store the previous state within the entity on load. Doesn't feel quite right but it's the most straightforward solution I've come across. https://stackoverflow.com/a/27531056/1356423

Comment: A bit ugly but yes that works! Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get old entity value in @HandleBeforeSave event to determine if a property is changed or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25233089/how-to-get-old-entity-value-in-handlebeforesave-event-to-determine-if-a-propert)