# Delete operation in BeforeSaveEventHandler is flushing the persisted data into DB

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jpql, spring-data-rest, spring-transactions

Delete operation in `BeforeSaveEvent` handler is flushing the loaded/persisted object into the database. And then invoking `BeforeSaveCustomValidator`.

1. Is there any way to restrict the insertion/flushing of non-validated data?
2. Can we isolate delete operation to a specific table to remove the entry rather than flushing entire object?

Comment: This answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25233089/how-to-get-old-entity-value-in-handlebeforesave-event-to-determine-if-a-propert will help you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get old entity value in @HandleBeforeSave event to determine if a property is changed or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25233089/how-to-get-old-entity-value-in-handlebeforesave-event-to-determine-if-a-propert)